# How to segregate the data into different columns in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset as shown below:-

```
[PM Status]       [Measure Date]

Success               23-Jan-2019
Success               24-Jan-2019
Exception            23-Jan-2019
Failure                  24-Jan-2019
Failure                  23-Jan-2019
```

According to the above data, I need the output from SQL as below:-

```
Meas Dt        Count(Success)         Count(failure)           Count(Exception)
 23-Jan            1                             1                          1
 24-Jan.           1                             1                          0
```

Is this possible to do this through an SQL query? If yes, please tell me how to. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option with some sample data.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable ([PM Status] VARCHAR(20), [Measure Date] DateTime)

INSERT INTO MyTable ([PM Status], [Measure Date]) VALUES 
    ('Success', '23-Jan-2019'), 
    ('Success', '24-Jan-2019'), 
    ('Exception', '23-Jan-2019'), 
    ('Failure', '24-Jan-2019'), 
    ('Failure', '23-Jan-2019'),
    ('Failure', '23-Jan-2019'),
    ('Failure', '23-Jan-2019'),
    ('Failure', '23-Jan-2019') 

SELECT * FROM MyTable

SELECT [PM Status], COUNT([PM Status]) AS Count_PM_Status, [Measure Date]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [Measure Date], [PM Status]
ORDER BY [Measure Date], [PM Status]
```

Here's a count version of the answer from @CR241.

```
select [Measure date],
  count(case when [PM Status] = 'Success' then [PM Status] end) as  [count (Success)],
  count(case when [PM Status] = 'Exception' then [PM Status] end) as  [count (Exception)],
  count(case when [PM Status] = 'Failure' then [PM Status] end) as [count (Failure)]
from MyTable
group by [Measure date];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've tried the count version of it, but I'm getting a syntax error "missing operator in query expression 'max(case when [PM Status = 'Success' then [PM Status] end)'"

Comment: @Yogesh B:  It sounds like a syntax error.  Try going to what definitely works, and then move step-by-step from that to what you want. The count(....) code above in my answer definitely works (at least for me) with the created MyTable. First get that working for yourself, and then try adjusting from that to your table and your formatting needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select [Measure date],
  max(case when [PM Status] = 'Success' then 1 end) as  [count (Success)],
  max(case when [PM Status] = 'Failure' then 1 end) as [count (Failure)],
  max(case when [PM Status] = 'Exception' then 1 else 0 end) as  [count (Exception)]
from table1
group by [Measure date];
```

Results:

```
Measure date    count (Success) count (Failure) count (Exception)
2019-01-23 00:00:00.000 1         1              1
2019-01-24 00:00:00.000 1         1              0
```

Comment: wouldn't it be count(....    vice max(... ?